# how to view this json data in flutter with Map<key,value>

Tags: json, flutter, view, flutter-layout

I'm getting my data from here into my **fetch** datatype

```
Map fetch = new Map();

eos.Transaction transaction = eos.Transaction()..actions = actions;
    _eosClient.pushTransaction(transaction, broadcast: true).then((trx) {
       print(trx); //for printing in console

      setState(() {
        fetch = trx;
      });
    });
```

And trying to show this data on my screen

```
Expanded(
                child: new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: fetch.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      String key = fetch.keys.elementAt(index);
                      return Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(key),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                            child: Text(
                              '${fetch['processed']['action_traces']}',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
              ),
```

Data in console looks like this and **want to print only bold data**

**processed**:{id: 93ae1319f9927becf0c164722fbb58a33518358e9b148f5af92140f6ab01543c, block_num: 51432026, block_time: 2019-09-25T06:21:11.000, producer_block_id: null, receipt: {status: executed, cpu_usage_us: 264, net_usage_words: 13}, elapsed: 264, net_usage: 104, scheduled: false, **action_traces**: [{action_ordinal: 1, creator_action_ordinal: 0, closest_unnotified_ancestor_action_ordinal: 0, receipt: {receiver: guru11111111, act_digest: 55e9b8f98bde721c3f3e53cf98a20814a5d426290b0bf55f842d97866bc71f6c, global_sequence: 488625827, recv_sequence: 353, auth_sequence: [[guru11111111, 423]], code_sequence: 25, abi_sequence: 14}, receiver: guru11111111, act: {account: guru11111111, name: getborrower, authorization: [{actor: guru11111111, permission: active}], data: {acc_name: guru}, hex_data: 0000000000a0af66}, context_free: false, elapsed: 69, console: **Borrower Name: guru      ID: 1      Location: varanasi      Phone Number: 8563070443      Loan amount: 4652007308841189376**, trx_id: 93ae1319f9927becf0c164722fbb58a33518358e9b148f

I have tried to make it look like this

```
{
    transaction_id: c459d2da5100afb1b4ab0352debfa4736aadd8c2e36529fe0861c9c8cadddeae, 
    processed: {
        id: c459d2da5100afb1b4ab0352debfa4736aadd8c2e36529fe0861c9c8cadddeae, 
        block_num: 51299894, 
        block_time: 2019-09-24T11:40:11.500, 
        producer_block_id: null, 
        receipt: {
            status: executed, 
            cpu_usage_us: 226, 
            net_usage_words: 13
        }, 
        elapsed: 226, 
        net_usage: 104, 
        scheduled: false, 
        action_traces: [
                        {
                            action_ordinal: 1, 
                            creator_action_ordinal: 0, 
                            closest_unnotified_ancestor_action_ordinal: 0, 
                            receipt: {
                                        receiver: guru11111111, 
                                        act_digest: 55e9b8f98bde721c3f3e53cf98a20814a5d426290b0bf55f842d97866bc71f6c, 
                                        global_sequence: 488304782, 
                                        recv_sequence: 329, 
                                        auth_sequence: [
                                            [guru11111111, 399]
                                        ], 
                                        code_sequence: 25, 
                                        abi_sequence: 14
                                        }, 
                            receiver: guru11111111, 
                            act: {
                                    account: guru11111111, 
                                    name: getborrower, 
                                    authorization: [
                                                        {
                                                            actor: guru11111111, 
                                                            permission: active
                                                        }
                                                    ], 
                                    data: 
                                        {
                                            acc_name: guru
                                        }, 
                                    hex_data: 0000000000a0af66
                                }, 
                            context_free: false, 
                            elapsed: 60, 
                            console: 
                            Borrower Name: guru
                            ID: 1
                            Location: varanasi
                            Phone Number: 8563070443, 
                            Loan Amount:465200 
                        }
```

**Text('${fetch['processed']['action_traces']}'),**

I'm able to print till 'action_traces' but **can not print inside 'action_traces'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after **action_traces** there is a array so i have given the index of array,
we can also use foreach loop for this.

```
//Text('${fetch['processed']['action_traces'][0]['console']}',)


Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: fetch.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
//                      String key = fetch.keys.elementAt(index);
                      print('${fetch[fetch.keys.elementAt(index)]}');
                      return Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '${fetch['processed']['action_traces'][0]['console']}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to create proper model for parsing this JSON and for that you can use Dart's official package [json_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation). After you have created model classes you will need to desrialise the json into Dart model and then use them as you want in your code.